# UML class diagram relationship between 2 classes

Tags: uml, modeling, visio

I have 2 classes called PostcodeLookup and Address. PostcodeLookp has an operation called 'Search' which returns an array of type Address. I am not sure how to represent the relation using UML.

[image]

Can somebody suggest me which relation I should use and why. I read few articles on these relations but I am always confused. Also suggest a better source to understand UML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use both variants, at the second one you see the connection more easily, but on the other hand, maybe you don't want to make too many lines.

That relationship is called Dependency.

### Definition of Dependency

A dependency is a relationship that signifies that a single or a set of model elements requires other model elements for their specification or implementation. This means that the complete semantics of the depending elements is either semantically or structurally dependent on the definition of the supplier element(s).

([VP UML help](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Class.html#dependency))

Comment: Thanks @Gangnus. I was little confused whether to show the dependency by drawing the line or not. Yes, as you said I don't want have too many lines :).

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to add any relation between *PostcodeLookup* and *Address*; you have to add a return parameter to your *Search* Operation which will be typed by Adress and that's all. 
This will implies a dependency from *PostcodeLookup* and *Address* but this dependency can be computed but not modeled as UML element.

Hoping it helps,

Regards,
EBR

Comment: Thanks @RedBeard. I have the return type as Address. I was confused whether to show the dependency explicitly or not.